# Updating View with respect to ViewCell in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, view, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a view with a list and a label.

I just placed a time picker inside the ViewCell of the corresponding list.

I want to know how can i get the selected time of the time picker into the corresponding label present in the view. !

How can i do it?

How can i update the label inside the `View` with respect to the time picker present in the `ViewCell` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it with the help of implementing INotifyPropertyChange to change the label in view update corresponding to picker in ViewCell.

Refer :

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Similar forum post : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/154124

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom element inside ViewCell, for example:

```
private ExtendedLabel ExtendedLabel
{
    get
    {
        return (ExtendedLabel)Element;
    }
}
```

Currently, you have an access to all public properties for your ExtendedLabel and through it you can change ViewModel state and do anything you want.

Comment: I have my every calculations okay, I'm facing the problem that UI of my view is not updating according to the picker selection.

Comment: In my view there is a ListView having a ViewCell containing picker .

And in the same view i have a label outside the ListView.

I want to the get the value of the picker inside the ViewCell to be displayed in the Label which is placed outside the Listview in the same View or Page !